# Apache Superset Installation - Load_Examples commad not working

Tags: python, apache-superset

I am trying to install Apache Superset and have followed all of the installation instructions from here.

https://gist.github.com/mark05e/d9cccae129dd11a21d7219eddd7d9923

I have got as far as trying to install the load_examples. When I run the command

Python superset load_examples I am getting this error

C:\Users\Superset\superset\Scripts
(superset) λ python superset load_examples
INFO:root:logging was configured successfully
C:\Users\Superset\Superset\superset\Scripts\flask_caching_*init*_.py:201: UserWarning: Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is effectively disabled.
warnings.warn(
Usage: superset [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'superset --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'load_examples'.

However, if I run python superset --help I can see that it is a command.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you’re trying use command load_examples. But the right command written with dash — load-examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can run on the virtual env

first of all you want to activate the environment

After than you can run this below code

```
superset load_examples
```

Answer (score 0):

First create superset config file and set environment variable

```
touch superset_config.py
export SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/app/superset/superset_config.py
```

In this case if you get warning to create security key follow below steps,

```
#generate security key
openssl rand -base64 42

#open config file
nano superset_config.py
```

And paste this into the config file

SECRET_KEY = 'YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_GENERATED_SECRET_KEY'

then save it and exit config file.

Now initialize db

```
export FLASK_APP=superset
```

Now load example will work

```
superset load_examples
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `load_examples` to `load-examples`.

I had the same problem when I was following the official [Superset documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/quickstart/).